# Can you mount a .wim image using DISM?

Tags: windows-7, mount, sysprep, dism

I created a custom script to mount a sysprepped Windows 7 .wim image to a directory so I can edit a specific file in the image and then unmount it. The script seems to work just fine; however, each time I try to use it, I seem to be getting some sort of error about the image, such as:

- The image is supposedly damaged or corrupted
- The image mounts but nothing appears in the directory

Is it possible to mount an sysprepped Windows 7 .wim image into a directory using DSIM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. The TechNet article [Mount and Modify an Image](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824814.aspx) shows how this is accomplished. You may also find useful information in the TechNet article [DISM Overview (Deployment Image Servicing and Management)](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh825236.aspx) to help with this. 
Sysprep should have no bearing on this issue.

Hope this helps,